# jupyter hub new user and admin add

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub

Hello I am currently a new user in JupyterHub,I am trying to add a new user and a new admin  by `c.Authenticator.allowed_users = {'user1'}` and `c.Authenticator.admin_users = {'user1'}` respectively. I comment out these 2 lines from the `jupyterhub_config.py`file too. But still I am getting "Invalid username or password ".
Regarding the password, I think for the first time "user1" will generate the password, when he/she will try to login. Is it right? Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

In your local system, you need to use your logged In username and password.

In docker, you need to do something like adduser  and follow the steps,

Ps: I'm also new to it and stumbled upon your question yesterday. Hope it helps anyone who's directed to this page